# Ingest GeoTIFF using geomesa-accumulo

Tags: java, gdal, geoserver, geotools, geomesa

I am trying to ingest geotiff data using geomesa-accumulo but getting the following error:

> **WARNING: Failed to load the GDAL native libs. This is not a problem unless you need to use the GDAL plugins: they won't be enabled.
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gdaljni in java.library.path**

I tried the following commands

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/libgdal.so
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/jni/libgdaljni.so
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/test/Project/2.0.2-geomesa/geotools/
```

After adding this, I verified whether everything is correct in the library path, using the following command

```
java -XshowSettings:properties
```

I created `gdal.jar` file after compiling  `gdal-2.3.0` source file  which i have added in `java.library.path`, I've also added 'geotools`in`java.library.path`. My`java.library.path` looks as below

```
  java.library.path = 
        /usr/lib/jni/libgdaljni.so
        /usr/lib/
        /usr/lib/libgdal.so
        /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64
        /usr/lib64
        /lib64
        /lib
        /usr/lib 
        /usr/local/lib/gdal
        /home/test/Project/2.0.2-geomesa/geotools/
```

Kindly help me to solve the warning that is shown. Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

As @Emilio suggested, I've tried adding `/usr/lib/jni/` along with the previous commands. My, updated commands are as follows.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/jni/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/test/Project/2.0.2-geomesa/geotools/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/libgdal.so
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/jni/libgdaljni.so
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/gdal
```

and my updated `java.library.path` is as shown below.

```
 java.library.path = 
        /usr/lib/jni/
        /usr/lib/
        /home/test/Project/2.0.2-geomesa/geotools/
        /usr/lib/libgdal.so
        /usr/lib/
        /usr/lib/jni/libgdaljni.so
        /usr/local/lib/gdal
        /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64
        /usr/lib64
        /lib64
        /lib
        /usr/lib
```

Now, I'm getting a new error message as

> Native library load failed. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no
>   gdalalljni in java.library.path Nov 13, 2018 11:11:51 PM
>   it.geosolutions.imageio.gdalframework.GDALUtilities loadGDAL WARNING:
>   Failed to load the GDAL native libs. This is not a problem unless you
>   need to use the GDAL plugins: they won't be enabled.
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.AllRegister()V

There is still no errors shown in the `geomesa` log file.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to point to the **folder** containing the native library, so in your case `/usr/lib/jni/`

Comment: I've tried your suggestion. A new error message is currently shown. I've updated the question with the current situation.

Comment: From the error message, it seems like you are still missing some of the native .so files that it's looking for.